# Как реализовать перемещение страницы к определёному месту по скроллу в JS

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Нужно реализовать перемещение страницы к определённому месту по скроллу на JS. Моя реализация не рабочая, при перемещении страница "застывает".

```js
var scroll = window.offsetHeight();
if (scroll == 0) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var offset = 0;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#why_we').offset().top - offset
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Согласен, только эти вопросы в основном ссылаются на библиотеки, которые не подходят, в моём случае нужно оследить скролл и уже переместиться

Comment: В любом случае, будь это библиотека или JS/JQuery - не работает.

Comment: Пример, который вы указали - это реализация по клику, в моём же случае, мне требуется сделать это по свайпу/скроллу